# Why is 1 == '1\n' true in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, equals, equality

The same goes for `'1\t'` (and probably others).

```
if (1 == '1\n') {
  console.log('Equal');
}
else {
  console.log('Not Equal');
}
```

Comment: because `Number('1\n')` is `1`, use `===` if you want a strict comparison.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said before if you compare `number == string`, it will automatically try to convert the string to a number. the `\n` and `\t` are simply whitespace characters and therefore ignored.

This and similar behaviour can be rather confusing leading to situations like this:

[image]

(Picture taken from: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/3imr8q/javascript/)

Comment: I knew the difference between == and ===. What I did not know, however, is that white spaces are ignored during the conversion of ==.

Answer (score 3):

> The [equality operator(`==`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators) **converts the operands if they are not of the same type**, then applies strict comparison. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

`1` is of type `Number` hence `'1\n'` is converted to `Number` first then `comparison` takes place!

And `Number()` constructor will convert the string`('1\n')` to `1` :-

### **`Number('1\n') === 1`**

In `Strict equality using ===`, Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the values have different types, the values are considered unequal.

Hence `1 === '1\n'` will be expressed as `false`