# Two different result for "1"+"1" & "1" - - "1" in javascript

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Coercion, Order Precedence and associativity can be confusing but I use below link to understand it,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

But I am still not getting why `"1"+"1"` resulting into `"11"` and `"1"- - "1"` resulting into `2`,

`- -` should be converted to `+` and it should process like `"1"+"1"`, What am I missing here?

You can test it here:

```js
console.log("1" + "1");
console.log("1"- - "1");
```

Comment: "*'- -' should be converted to +*" - why?

Comment: With quotes around the operands the + is interpreted as string concatenation. The - - operators are casting the operands to numeric and subtracting -1 from 1 resulting in 2.

Comment: Just add parentheses according to the precedence/associativity rules, and you should have your answer.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this topic also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619870/why-is-1-1-n-true-in-javascript/36620136

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* Different operators perform different kinds of type conversion.

Comment: *"`- -` should be converted to `+`"* is absolutely not how operators work, in any language. "Conversion" does not happen on operators. `- -` is no more converted to `+` than `a * 1/b` is converted to `a / b`.

Comment: Conversion and precedence comes later. First, the parser tries to successfully parse as much as possible. Your expression is parsed as string literal, minus operator, unary minus, string literal. Rest is common sense.

Answer (score 7):

The second `-` of the two `-`s is interpreted as unary `-`. The unary operator has higher precedence so `"1"- - "1"` is the same as `"1" - (-"1")` which is then the same as `"1" - (-1)` and since `-` is only used on numbers, the aforementionned operation becomes `1 - (-1)` which evaluates to `2`.

Comment: I'm not sure precedence comes into it - there is no other reasonable way to group these operators and operands.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm not sure I'm following you. Are you talking about the parenthesis I added?

Comment: Yes.  What I mean is - I don't think you can reasonably place parentheses anywhere else.  And that's basically equivalent to not needing to worry about precedence.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ah! Yeah yeah, sure. I just added them for the sake of explaining.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you! and Yes 'parentheses ' helped me in understanding.

Comment: Indeed - I agree that the parentheses help make it clear what's going on!

Comment: @JackRyder You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

`“1”+“1”` will be interpreted as a string concatenation. When evaluating an expression, `+` will do a concatenation if one of the operand is of type `string` which is not the case for the operator `-`.

`“1” - - “1”` in javascript, the operator `-` tries to do a parsing of the operands it has. If it cannot parse them into number it will return NaN. So `“1” - - “1”` is similar to `“1” - (- “1”)` . What happens is that because there is the operator `-` there will be a parsing of `"1"` to number (first operand) and a parsing of the second operand `(-"1")` also to number.

Actually both operators are a little different:

- `"foo" + 1` will return `foo1`, because + will do a concatenation
- whereas: `"foo" - 1` will return `NaN` because the first operand cannot be parsed into a number. The same rule applies to the operator `/` and `*`.

Comment: *"If it cannot parse them into number an Exception is thrown."* That's not correct.

Comment: *"because the first operand is of type string"* It will do concatenation if *either* operand is a string.

Comment: @rockstar, you're right. I have edited my answer